# KnockoutJS binding when source is null/undefined

Tags: binding, knockout.js

Is there a shorter/cleaner way to do the null/undefined testing?

```
<select data-bind="options: SelectedBusinessLine() ? SelectedBusinessLine().Clusters() : [],
                               optionsText: 'Title',
                               value: SelectedCluster,
                               optionsCaption: 'Select Cluster..'">
            </select>
```

Instead of

```
data-bind="options: SelectedBusinessLine() ? SelectedBusinessLine().Clusters() : [],
```

i would like

```
data-bind="options: SelectedBusinessLine().Clusters(),
```

give or take the ()

Or at least a simpler null operator check '??' SelectedBusinessLine ?? []

Or a  binding param to auto check for null or silent fail.

Any ideas if this is possible?

Answer (score 78, accepted):

[This page](http://www.knockmeout.net/2011/08/simplifying-and-cleaning-up-views-in.html) provides several solutions. The relevant part is this one:

Protecting against null objects

If you have an observable that contains an object and you want to bind to properties of that object, then you need to be careful if there is a chance that it can be null or undefined. You may write your binding like:

```
<span data-bind="text: selectedItem() ? selectedItem().name() : 'unknown'"></span>
```

There are a number of ways to handle this one. The preferred way would be to simply use the template binding:

```
var viewModel = {
  items: ko.observableArray(),
  selectedItem: ko.observable()
};

<ul data-bind="template: { name: 'editorTmpl', data: selectedItem }"></ul>
<script id="editorTmpl" type="text/html">
  <li>
    <input data-bind="value: name" />
  </li>
</script>
```

With this method, if `selectedItem` is null, then it just won’t render anything. So, you would not see unknown as you would have in the original binding. However, it does have the added benefit of simplifying your bindings, as you can now just specify your property names directly rather than `selectedItem().name`. This is the easiest solution.

Just for the sake of exploring some options, here are a few alternatives:

You could use a computed observable, as we did before.

```
viewModel.selectedItemName = ko.computed(function() {
  var selected = this.selected();
  return selected ? selected.name() : 'unknown';
}, viewModel);
```

However, this again adds some bloat to our view model that we may not want and we might have to repeat this for many properties.

You could use a custom binding like:

```
<div data-bind="safeText: { value: selectedItem, property: 'name', default: 'unknown' }"></div>

ko.bindingHandlers.safeText = {
  update: function(element, valueAccessor, allBindingsAccessor) {
    var options = ko.utils.unwrapObservable(valueAccessor()),
    value = ko.utils.unwrapObservable(options.value),
    property = ko.utils.unwrapObservable(options.property),
    fallback = ko.utils.unwrapObservable(options.default) || "",
    text;

    text = value ? (options.property ? value[property] : value) : fallback;

    ko.bindingHandlers.text.update(element, function() { return text; });
  }
};
```

Is this better than the original? I would say probably not. It does avoid the JavaScript in our binding, but it is still pretty verbose.

One other option would be to create an augmented observable that provides a safe way to access properties while still allowing the actual value to be null. Could look like:

```
ko.safeObservable = function(initialValue) {
  var result = ko.observable(initialValue);
  result.safe = ko.dependentObservable(function() {
    return result() || {};
  });

  return result;
};
```

So, this is just an observable that also exposes a computed observable named safe that will always return an empty object, but the actual observable can continue to store null.

Now, you could bind to it like:

```
<div data-bind="text: selectedItem.safe().name"></div>
```

You would not see the unknown value when it is null, but it at least would not cause an error when `selectedItem` is null.

I do think that the preferred option would be using the template binding in this case, especially if you have many of these properties to bind against.

Comment: The only problem with template that sometimes i want to show the select box empty of options and not hide it. I think the framework should provide a way for us to not bloat the source with if null else code..

Comment: For the example here for templating didn't actually work - if the "data" portion of the template was null then I got binding errors.  I was able to fix this by applying the "if" attribute for the template binding:  <div data-bind="template: { if: item(), data: item(), name: 'someTemplate' }"></div>

Comment: @DrewMiller, I think it is the jquery templating engine that takes care of the null object handling. When using the native knockout template engine, the if attribute does the trick.

Comment: Just FYI [ko.dependentObservable is deprecated](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/dependentObservables.html) by ko.computed now.

Comment: See "with" below as the best answer

Answer (score 64):

One way not mentioned in the [excellent page](http://www.knockmeout.net/2011/08/simplifying-and-cleaning-up-views-in.html) referenced by another answer is to use `with`

```
<div data-bind="with: selecteditem">
    <form>
        <fieldset>
            <div>
                <label>first name</label>
                <input data-bind="value: firstname"></input>
            </div>
            <div>
                <label>lasst name</label>
                <input data-bind="value: lastname"></input>
            </div>
        </fieldset>
        <div>
            <a href="#" data-bind="click: $root.savechanges">Save</a>
        </div>
    </form>
</div>
```

This whole UI will disappear if `selecteditem` is null.

Comment: (Which is what we want)

Comment: Simplest, most elegant. Thanks!

Comment: This should be the accepted answer. The current accepted answer is too complicated to make such a simple requirement work. This is one of the core features of `with`.

Comment: if you need to access something in the 'scope' above use `$parent`

Comment: even with latest versions of everything i was finding the *with binding* somehow prevented custom bindingHandlers from wiring up

Comment: @Simon_Weaver what should we do, if we want to render the view even when selecteditem is null?

Comment: @NikolaMitev this question was really about how to avoid null reference errors when you have many bindings that would cause such errors if they were present in the dom. You could ether show a completely different dummy UI (repeating all the fields), set some kind of empty object for the data (instead of null) or you’d have to handle it for ever field so it wouldn’t break with null. Hard to tell what to recommend without seeing your Ui

Comment: @Simon_Weaver I was about to avoid duplicating the UI with ifnot: VM is null ' binding and also I don't have explicit defined VM (since it has pretty much properties) but simply mapping.fromJS was enough.

Answer (score 4):

The "With" works (probably the others works too...)

But with the "With" the role UI disappear/appear even if there are conditions inside... For Example... I need to set a Status (true/false) button, but only if the Status isn't null...

```
<!-- ko ifnot: Status() == null -->
<span data-bind="if: Status">
    <a class="rk-button rk-red-action" data-bind="click: changeStatus"><i class="rk-ico rk-ico-save"></i>Desativar</a>
</span>
<span data-bind="ifnot: Status">
    <a class="rk-button rk-black-action" data-bind="click: changeStatus"><i class="rk-ico rk-ico-save"></i>Ativar</a>
</span>
<!-- /ko -->
```

This works. In this case.

But sometimes just the "With" works like Simon_Weaver said!

Comment: I never knew about `ifnot` :-)

Comment: be cautious about this if your `Status` observable is a computed observable and you are also enabling ko.options.deferUpdates = true;` as you can still get null errors - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43341484

Answer (score 2):

Most of the above solutions didn't work for me quite out of the box, since I only wanted to apply this to a single element in a `foreach` so I modified the accepted answer's approach a bit:

```
<span data-bind="text: ((typeof info).localeCompare('undefined')) ? info : ''"></span>
```

Answer (score 1):

I prefer this method

Create a custom binding

```
ko.bindingHandlers.safeText = {
    update: function (element, valueAccessor, allBindingsAccessor) {
        try {
            var tryGetValue = valueAccessor()();
            ko.bindingHandlers.text.update(element, valueAccessor());
        } catch (e) {
            ko.bindingHandlers.text.update(element, function () { return ""; });
        }
    }
};
```

Usage

```
data-bind="safeText: function() { return my().nested.object.property; }
```

The only extra stuff you need to add is to wrap your original value with 'function() { return ... }'

This however, will stop all errors beneath the value call.  You could improve the custom binding by only looking for 'undefined' exceptions.  You may also like to improve this binding by adding in a default text option.

Answer (score 1):

Most of these solutions do not work in a certain case for me, where I am setting an attribute:

```
<div role="combobox" data-bind="attr: {
  'aria-activedescendant': activedescendant() ? activedescendant().id : null
}">
  ...
</div>
```

The `template` and `with` bindings would not work here, because if I did not have an active descendant, then my div would be empty. For my solution, I created an observable method:

```
ko.observable.fn.get = function (propertyName, defaultValue) {
    var
    self = this(),
    propertyValue;

    if (self != null) {
        propertyValue = ko.unwrap(self[propertyName]);
    }

    return propertyValue || defaultValue;
}
```

Which allows me to change my binding to this:

```
<div role="combobox" data-bind="attr: {
  'aria-activedescendant': activedescendant.get('id')}">
  ...
</div>
```