# Knockout.js: Unable to parse bindings from JSON

Tags: jquery, ajax, json, knockout.js, knockout-2.0

I have a view model that fetches JSON through AJAX, and creates a new Task, but Knockout keep giving me a binding error.

If I hard code the data coming from the server straight in my view model, I don't receive any errors.

My view model creates new task, that has an id, a question and a number of alteratives, which in itself has a text and correct boolean flag.

The following code works perfectly fine:

```
function Task(data) {
    var self = this;

    self.id = data.id;
    self.question = ko.observable(data.question);

    var alts = new Array();
    $(data.alternatives).each(function(index){
        alts.push(new Alternative(data.alternatives[index].alternative, data.alternatives[index].correct));
    });

    self.alternatives = ko.observableArray(alts);
}
function Alternative(alternativeText, correctAnswer) {
    var self         = this;
    self.alternative = ko.observable(alternativeText);
    self.correct     = ko.observable(correctAnswer);
}
function TaskViewModel() {
    var self = this;

    var data = {
        id: 5,
        question: 'test',
        alternatives: [{
            alternative: 'alt 1',
            correct: false
        },{
            alternative: 'alt 2',
            correct: true
        },{
            alternative: 'alt 3',
            correct: false
        }]
    };

    self.task = new Task(data);
}
```

But if I exhcange the hard coded `data` variable with real data from the server:

```
function TaskViewModel() {
    var self = this;

    $.getJSON('/data', function(data){
        self.task = new Task(data);
    });
}
```

Knockout gives me this error:

```
Error: Unable to parse bindings.
Message: ReferenceError: Can't find variable: task;
Bindings value: value: task.question
```

The data from the URL looks like the following:

```
{"id":5,"question":"test","alternatives":[{"alternative":"alt 1","correct":false},{"alternative":"alt 2","correct":true},{"alternative":"alt 3","correct":false}]}
```

I can't seem to figure out why this won't work :/

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your view model doesn't actually have a `task` property by the time your bindings are applied.  You need to give it something to bind to.

There's a couple of ways you can handle this.

Probably the easiest way would be to make `task` observable and set it as the result of the ajax call.  You may need to adjust you bindings to account for this change.

```
function TaskViewModel() {
    var self = this;
    self.task = ko.observable();

    $.getJSON('/data', function(data){
        self.task(new Task(data));
    });
}
```

A more flexible option would be to add a separate initialization method for your `Task` objects and set the task (uninitialized). Then as a result of the ajax call, call the initialization method to initialize it.  You would have to adjust the initialization code for your task objects of course.

```
function TaskViewModel() {
    var self = this;
    self.task = new Task();

    $.getJSON('/data', function(data){
        self.task.init(data);
    });
}

function Task() {
    var self = this;
    self.id = ko.observable();
    self.question = ko.observable();
    self.alternatives = ko.observableArray();

    self.init = function (data) {
        self.id(data.id);
        self.question(data.question);
        self.alternatives(ko.utils.arrayForEach(data.alternatives, function (item) {
            return new Alternative(item.alternative, item.correct);
        }));
    };
}
```

Comment: Thanks man. I actually figured this out after the things you mentioned with an initialization method (which you've presented here). That made it work prefectly :)

Answer (score 4):

This post contains a number of ways you can handle binding when source is null.

[KnockoutJS binding when source is null/undefined](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11387501/knockoutjs-binding-when-source-is-null-undefined)

If you're OK with your unbindable UI from disappearing I recommend using [`with`](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/with-binding.html)

If `selectedItem` is null then the element won't even be shown.

```
<div data-bind="with: selecteditem">
    <form>
        <fieldset>
            <div>
                <label>first name</label>
                <input data-bind="value: firstname"></input>
            </div>
            <div>
                <label>lasst name</label>
                <input data-bind="value: lastname"></input>
            </div>
        </fieldset>
        <div>
            <a href="#" data-bind="click: $root.savechanges">Save</a>
        </div>
    </form>
</div>
```

Comment: note: with this method this div is removed from the DOM when `selecteditem` is null so if you've got non 'live' event handlers attached to it then it may not work