# Get error in Knockout.js and MVC 3

Tags: asp.net-mvc, knockout.js

this is my sample but not work and get this error in chrome
Uncaught Error: Unable to parse binding attribute.
Message: ReferenceError: ProductName is not defined;
Attribute value: text: ProductName

Action Code:

```
    public ActionResult GetProducts()
    {
        var product = _db.Products;
        return Json(product, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
    }
```

Html :

```
    <table id="timesheets" class="table table-striped table-hover table-condensed">   
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>ProductName</th>
                <th>CategoryID</th>
                <th>UnitPrice</th>
                <th>Discontinued</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody data-bind="foreach: viewModel.Products">
            <tr>
                <td data-bind="text: ProductName"></td>
                <td data-bind="text: CategoryID"></td>
                <td data-bind="text: UnitPrice"></td>
                <td data-bind="text: year"></td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
```

Javascript Code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">

    $(function () {
        viewModel.loadProducts();
        ko.applyBindings(viewModel);
    });

    function Product(data) {
        this.ProductID = ko.observable(data.ProductID);
        this.ProductName = ko.observable(data.ProductName);
        this.CategoryID = ko.observable(data.CategoryID);
        this.UnitPrice = ko.observable(data.UnitPrice);
        this.Discontinued = ko.observable(data.Discontinued);
    }

    var viewModel = {

        Products: ko.observableArray([]),

        loadProducts: function () {

            var self = this;
            $.getJSON(
                '/Home/GetProducts',
                function (products) {
                    self.Products.removeAll();

                    $.each(products, function (index, item) {
                        self.Products.push(new Product(item));
                    });
                }
            );
        }
    };

</script>
```

please Help, thanks

Answer (score 0):

Please check attributes/properties in `_db.Products`. They have not found `ProductName` may be it is missing. If you are using EF then refresh your EntityFramework model again. Or you can also check whether `ProductName` is empty or null by using alert like:

```
function Product(data) {
        alert(data.ProductName);
        this.ProductID = ko.observable(data.ProductID);
        this.ProductName = ko.observable(data.ProductName);
        this.CategoryID = ko.observable(data.CategoryID);
        this.UnitPrice = ko.observable(data.UnitPrice);
        this.Discontinued = ko.observable(data.Discontinued);
    }
```

Comment: get product action return data to json request , i check this , return data is : [{"ProductID":1,"ProductName":"Chai","SupplierID":1,"CategoryID":1,"QuantityPerUnit":"10 boxes x 20 bags","UnitPrice":18.0000,"UnitsInStock":39,"UnitsOnOrder":0,"ReorderLevel":10,"Discontinued":false}]

Comment: Ok now put alert in 
`$.getJSON(
                '/Home/GetProducts',
                function (products) {
                    alert(products.ProductName);
                    self.Products.removeAll();

                    $.each(products, function (index, item) {
                        self.Products.push(new Product(item));
                    });
                }
            );`
and see whether data in ProductName attribute is successfully get or not..

Comment: Please see this thread it is may be binding problem: [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13333567/knockout-js-unable-to-parse-bindings-from-json)

Comment: data recieve ok, i think my script or html is not ok

Comment: Use this in your viewmodel:
`var self = this;
self.task = ko.observable();`
I think this should work..

Comment: or you can also check this:
`var self = this;self.ProductName = ko.observable();`

Comment: i use this tutorial for done my sample but not work,  http://cgeers.com/2012/10/06/single-page-application-with-knockout-js-part-1/