# Is this the correct behavior of KnockoutJS binding when source is undefined?

Tags: knockout.js, binding

I came across an issue that I need to understand conceptually. I could not find documentation or any other source of information that would settle my unrest regarding this behavior:

Is this behavior expected? When I have a computed observable based on another observable set to an empty object, referencing a not yet existent property, nothing gets rendered/bound in the view, the viewModel data is simply unaware of the existence of this undefined property... It's a common case where you have an observable initialized as an empty object, to later have it set to a non-empty object, from which you may need to access the non-empty object's properties.

It is contrasting with what has been discussed in the following links (is it?):

[KnockoutJS binding when source is null/undefined](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11387501/knockoutjs-binding-when-source-is-null-undefined)

[Simplifying and Cleaning Up Views in KnockoutJS](http://www.knockmeout.net/2011/08/simplifying-and-cleaning-up-views-in.html)

Please review the snippet (and comments) as below:

Run the script and click on the button for the behavior!

```js
var viewModel = function() {
  var self = this;
  //not empty object literal observable initialized
  self.object = ko.observable({p1: "Born ready"});
  self.objectP1 = ko.pureComputed(function() {
    return self.object().p1;
  });

  //empty object literal observable initialized
  self.objectEmptyOnInit = ko.observable({});
  
  //computed observable based on a (undefined) property, is simply discarded, not rendered in view, not present in viewModel $data
  self.objectP1EmptyOnInit = ko.pureComputed(function() {
    return self.objectEmptyOnInit().p1;
  });
  
  //same behavior as this computed observable, returning explicitly undefined
  self.objectP2EmptyOnInit = ko.pureComputed(function() {
    return undefined;
  });


  self.debugInfo = function(item) {
    return ko.toJSON(item);
  };


};

ko.applyBindings(new viewModel());
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/knockout/3.2.0/knockout-min.js"></script>

<span data-bind="text: objectP1"></span>
<br />
<span data-bind="text: objectP1EmptyOnInit"></span>
<br />
<button data-bind="click: function() { $root.objectEmptyOnInit({p1: 'Look Im born!'}) }">Give birth to objectEmptyOnInit</button>

<div style="border: white dotted thin; clear: both">
  <h4>Debug viewModel $data</h4>
  <pre data-bind="text: debugInfo($data)"></pre>
  <div data-bind="visible: objectEmptyOnInit()">
  <span>Not a clue about objectP1EmptyOnInit</span>
  </div>
  <div data-bind="visible: objectEmptyOnInit().p1">
  <span>Here comes objectP1EmptyOnInit</span>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: It's difficult to underrstand this question. Please, be more explicit and say what you expect to happen and what happens in each case. If I run the snippet everything works as I expect. That's probably because I've been using KO (an JS) for along time. If you're more explicit, I'll bve glad to help you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's a knockout default behavior. The computed observables are smart enough to avoid errors arising from undefined properties originated from empty objects. The snippet is proof of that. It just works.