# Knockout JS: How to subscribe to changes in code similar to how binding handlers work

Tags: javascript, knockout.js

Let's say there is a path in the view-model property which needs to be observed, like this:

```
<div data-bind="myBindingHandler: { data1: prop1().prop2().prop3() }"></div>
```

This is easy to do in HTML with `data-bind` and binding handler, but doing this manually in JS code with `.subscribe()` is tedious.

Is there a way in KO to be able to somehow give the same string and listen to changes? I imagine it would be something like this:

```
viewModelInstance.prop1.observe("prop2().prop3()", function (newValue) {
  console.log('prop3 value is", newValue);
});
```

I'm pretty sure somewhere in the KO implementation it's possible, but I wonder if it's really exposed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a `ko.computed` for this. Note that every change in the observable tree will trigger an evaluation. If one of the values can be `undefined` or `null`, you'll need to check accordingly.

```js
var a = ko.observable({
  b: ko.observable({
    c: ko.observable(1)
  })
})
  
ko.computed(function() {
  console.log("C is now:", a().b().c());
});

a().b().c(2);
a().b({
  c: ko.observable(3)
});
a({
  b: ko.observable({
    c: ko.observable(4)
  })
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/knockout/3.2.0/knockout-min.js"></script>
```

**`undefined` checks**

There are several ways you can go about null checking a chain of observables. Personally, I prefer something along these lines:

```js
function unwrapChain(obs, path) {
  return path.reduce((o, k) => o ? ko.unwrap(o[k]) : o, obs);
}


var a = {
  b: ko.observable({
    c: ko.observable({
      d: ko.observable(1)
    })
  })
};

console.log(unwrapChain(a, ["b", "c", "d"]));
console.log(unwrapChain(a, ["b", "f", "d"]));
console.log(unwrapChain(a, ["b", "c"]).d());
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/knockout/3.2.0/knockout-min.js"></script>
```

Comment: a `pureComputed` would be better though, don't you think?

Comment: I'm worried however about `If one of the values can be undefined or null, you'll need to check accordingly`. How to do that easily?

Comment: Maybe a have a "safe" observable? like this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11387501/knockoutjs-binding-when-source-is-null-undefined But I'm not sure how to use that

Comment: another thing to take into account is the subscription management

Comment: @DonBox A `pureComputed` would not work in this case, because the computed body is not a *pure* function. It has side effects, as it logs to console. Read the documentation about pureComputed, it's important to understand the use-case.

Comment: I've added an example on how you can do `undefined` checks, but it's up to you what you prefer. For disposal logic, I'd recommend checking the `disposeWhen` option. Let me know if you need help with that.

Comment: @ZoltánTamási in my scenario, I only want to listen to a value in the "binding path". So I think the body of the computed will only contain `return a().b().c();` I think this is a pure function, correct?

Comment: @DonBox In that case it is indeed.