# Knockout deferUpdates conflict with 'if' binding

Tags: knockout.js

I very often use the `if` binding in knockout to hide something, with the added bonus that I don't need to worry about null reference errors inside the `if`. In this example if `address()` is null then the whole block is removed so you avoid having to deal with null checking for every property. This would not be the case had I used the `visible` binding.

```
<div data-bind="if: address()">
    You live at:
    <p data-bind="text: address().street.toUpperCase()"></p>            
</div>
```

This is the simplest case above - and yes I would generally use this pattern with the `<!-- ko -->` comment syntax.

What is actually causing me problems is when I use a more complex `computed` value and enable the `ko.options.deferUpdates` option :

```
<div data-bind="if: hasAddress()">
    You live at:
    <p data-bind="text: address().street.toUpperCase()"></p>            
</div>
```

The simplest implementation of this `computed` observable might be something like this :

```
this.hasAddress = ko.computed(function () { return _this.address() != null; });
```

This all works great until I do the following:

> 1) set `ko.options.deferUpdates = true` before creating the observables.
>
> 2) `address()` will start off as null and everything is fine
>
> 3) set `address()` to `{ street: '123 My Street' }`. Again everything works fine.
>
> 4) reset `address()` to null. I get a null error because `address().street` is 
>    null :-(
>
> Here is a fiddle to illustrate the problem : https://jsfiddle.net/g5gvfb7x/2/

It seems that unfortunately due to the order in which the micro-tasks runs it tries to recalculate the `text` binding before the `if` binding and so you still get a null error that normally wouldn't occur.

---

I'm a little scared about this since I use this pattern a lot :-(

Comment: good catch, the same issue in v.3.4.2. Starting from now, i will follow your hint to always log ko.errors along with window.errors during development.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When using `deferUpdates`, Knockout internally uses a `dirty` event to notify all computed observables of a change in their dependencies and to schedule updates, which happens in depth-first order. The problem here occurs because bindings ignore the `dirty` event and wait for a `change` event, which will happen in a breadth-first order.

The fix has to happen in Knockout to make bindings respond to the `dirty` events. This has already been checked in for the upcoming version (3.5.0): https://github.com/knockout/knockout/issues/2226

Answer (score 0):

**Good news** - if you have turned on `ko.options.deferUpdates` and not even realized you have broken your app then the chances are your user won't see an error because errors from micro tasks are raised on `ko.onError` or `window.onerror` and the UI appears to recover. But if like me you're logging these errors then it's bad.

**Good news** - if you can identify which observables you use in an `if` binding you can do the following and turn deferUpdates off and back on:

```
// turn deferUpdates off and back on again
var deferUpdatesState = ko.options.deferUpdates;
ko.options.deferUpdates = false;
this.hasAddress = ko.computed(function () { return _this.address() != null; }); 
ko.options.deferUpdates = deferUpdatesState;
```

This can be made into a helper function. There could be more complex issues if the `hasAddress` computed has more complicated dependencies. But for the simpler case like this it's fine.

---

**Bad news** - you unfortunately can't do the following:

```
ko.computed(function () { return _this.address() != null; }).extend({ deferred: false });
```

This is just due to the way that deferUpdates works internally (from looking at source).

---

Still wondering if there is a better solution than this helper function, or a way to rewrite the `if` binding to maybe do something clever in the binding to cover this case.

---

Edit: Thanks to @Tomalak for mentioning `with` binding. I don't think it is the complete solution I'm looking for, but it can certainly be used in conjunction with any existing `if` bindings (that have complex rules) like this. Might be the safest fix if trying to go through an existing app.

```
<div>
    <div data-bind="if: hasAddress">
        You live at:
        <!-- ko with: address() -->
        <p data-bind="text: street.toUpperCase()"></p>          
        <!-- /ko -->
    </div>

    <div data-bind="if: !hasAddress()">
        Sorry! I don't know where you live!
    </div>

</div>
```

Comment: The documentation talks about potential breakage of existing apps pretty early on and also offers a resolution. Have you seen it? (CTRL+F "although you may be able to work around these issues") http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/deferred-updates.html

Comment: Yes I saw all those - and I meant to mention `ko.tasks.runEarly()` here. I will add a note about it but unfortunately it didn't help. It seems to just be down to the order the tasks are run.

Comment: Here's a copy of the fiddle where I set `runEarly` many times https://jsfiddle.net/g5gvfb7x/3/. And yes I fully understand the risks or breaking an existing app, but I'm trying to find the best way to get `if` working with a `computed` alongside `ko.options.deferUpdates` and not seeing a very elegant solution yet.

Comment: Yeah, I was just throwing it in, I had even not begun tinkering with it. Curious issue, I wonder what's the reason. (TBH I would have written the whole thing differently and apparently not have run into this at all in this case https://jsfiddle.net/g5gvfb7x/4/)

Comment: yes it's one of those fun - but also not fun things. The `if` works fine too if you just put `if: address`. It's only when I have more complex conditions using a computed like `if: showAddressPanel` or `if: isEditing` that I'm running into issues. These can't easily be reduced to `with` or a simpler `if`. At least I know now what to look for and I'm glad I'm logging JS errors or I'd never have even seen this.

Comment: Interestingly, your example also fails if using 3.3.0 and the deferred updates plugin: https://jsfiddle.net/g5gvfb7x/6/. Can you open an issue at https://github.com/knockout/knockout?

Comment: @MichaelBest sure. Thanks for running the test

Comment: If you're willing to use a customized version of Knockout, you can change the line that reads `if (target._deferUpdates && !this[computedState].disposeWhenNodeIsRemoved) {` to `if (target._deferUpdates) {`

Comment: I've created a Github issue and will check in a fix shortly. https://github.com/knockout/knockout/issues/2226

Comment: @MichaelBest really appreciate your quick fix of this issue (thought I already replied to you). If you want the bounty points please add your comment as an answer and I'll send them your way.